# jQuery Intellisense does not shown another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, intellisense

I have created one JavaScript file `First.js` and added a function: `function Testing(name) {}`.

I have created another JavaScript file `Second.js` and created a new function: `function AccessFirst() {}`.

Inside the function I am calling `Testing(name)` (the file in `First.js`) but Intellisense is not showing when editing `Second.js`.

But I need the Intellisense here. How do I get Intellisense to work when I'm editing `Second.js`?

Comment: @haim770: I think they meant Intellisense, which would mean Visual Studio.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx "JavaScript IntelliSense" -- it sounds like you are having trouble getting the IDE to actually do what it purports to do, autocomplete the available functions for you as you program. Is that the question?

Comment: Edited for clarity. Please consider reopening. HELP THE NOOBS!

Comment: Please read my question carefully otherwise see this post "How to show the intelligence in jQuery external script function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to add this line to your `second.js`:

```
/// <reference path="path to your first.js" />
```

When you add the above line in your `second.js`, intellisense will show up suggestions based on what is present in `first.js`